# Are multiple objects being created?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a simple React library but I'm unsure whether multiple objects are being created unnecessarily.

I have an `app.js` file:

```
class App {
  method1() {

  }
  method2() {

  }
}
export default new App();
```

I also have an `index.js` file:

```
import app from './app.js';
...
export default app;
```

In the `index.js` of my React project (where I make use of the library) I use:

```
import MyLibrary from 'react-library';
...
MyLibrary.method1();
```

and then I do the same in some of my components too:

```
import MyLibrary from 'react-library';
...
MyLibrary.method2();
```

Is the second import of `MyLibrary` a different object to the first `MyLibrary`?

Comment: In my understanding, yes. Point is, every module should have its own scope. So importing a module in a file should be accessible in its scope only. So, yes they are different objects.

Comment: I've tried to test this and the results suggest the same object??? I pass a value to a dummy property in `method1`. When I then log the `MyLibrary` after the second import, the property exists.

Comment: Thats because of `new App()`. You module is exporting an instance. So whenever you import, you are importing a reference. So updating it will update the object at that memory location. Try to return a class and create object in every file.

Comment: Of course - totally forgot about "pass by reference"

Comment: So if I want to make the same object available in other parts of my app then I will need pass down in the normal fashion I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the second import of MyLibrary a different object to the first
>   MyLibrary?

In general the object returned by the `import` is cached (same behaviour as nodejs `require`), multiples import of the same file will result in the same object being returned. So the answer to your question is No, you're dealing with the same reference in memory.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html

> Every filesystem access is cached so that multiple parallel or serial
>   requests to the same resource are merged

in your particular case, as suggested in the comments section, you're exporting an instance, not the class itself.

```
export default new App();
```

consequently each component that import that file will deal with the same instance.
This is a singleton pattern, don't know if it is the desired behaviour, if you want that each component has it's own instance you should export the class instead.

```
export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Quick question - `method1` is an `init` function that accepts a number of options. I want to avoid having to pass the same options in every component that makes use of the library. Any ideas on a good way to make the App instance available everywhere?

Comment: well you can have a default options object inside the class and extend this object in case one is passed to the init method, otherwise use the default. indeed if method1() is called without parameters you use the default configuration.

Comment: Options will always need to be passed in my case unfortunately.

Comment: not sure if i understand correctly,  why you have to pass options every time?  if your aim is to avoid passing the same options multiple times i think this is a perfect scenario to set a default object in your class  with a base configuration and extend it  when the method is called with a new configuration. this way you can remove any redundant parameters from the call. hope it helps

Comment: It's a library that will be used by different people and it links to their backends. Therefore, they need to provide URLs for the backends which are going to be different for every user.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a singgleton there, put a breakpoint in the constructor and you will see how only one instance is created.